# Creating a slimmed down version of the jQuery library

Tags: jquery

When creating a slimmed down version of jQuery, is there a simple way to decide what parts of the API I need and what parts of the API I don't need? Do I have to read through all my code and see what parts of the API are used, or is there an easier/quicker way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps google's closure compiler? (https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you take [zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/) a chance?

It is a javascript framework which allows you to select some parts of jQuery individually and pack them into a custom set, ready for use.

So if you need only a few functionalities (e.g: just ajax, without selectors) you can select them in their web, then download your custom set of jquery parts, and work with it.

It's really nice if you are worried about the total size of the file you have to include.

Comment: How can I slim down zepto.js? And why is it better than slimming down jQuery itself?

Comment: You haven't slim down zepto. You have to select the features you want to use and download them for use. Zepto it's not better than slim down jQuery itself. It is just an alternative that could be handy.